Excel: Dynamic stacking or arrays n-number of times
Problem: Stacking arrays horizontally/vertically n-number of times
Examples:

Horizontal array {"A", "B", "C"} stacked horizontally n=3 times = {"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"}
Horizontal array {"A", "B", "C"} stacked vertically
n=2 times = {"A", "B", "C"; "A", "B", "C"}

Undesirable solutions:
This problem is trivial manually by just providing the n-amount of arrays to a VSTACK() or HSTACK() -formula. A brute-force dynamic solution can be made using vector manipulation (e.g., TOCOL() and TRANSPOSE()) and MAKEARRAY() to create an index of the desired size and then INDEX(MATCH()) the values to the structure.

Manual (horizontal):
=HSTACK({"A", "B", "C"},{"A", "B", "C"},{"A", "B", "C"})
Manual (vertical): =VSTACK({"A", "B", "C"},{"A", "B", "C"})
Dynamic brute-force (horizontal): =LET(Array,{"A","B","C"},n,3,INDEX(Array,MATCH(TOROW(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array))*MAKEARRAY(1,n,LAMBDA(r,c,1)),0,TRUE),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array)),0)))
Dynamic brute-force (vertical): =LET(Array,{"A","B","C"},n,2,INDEX(Array,MATCH(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array))*MAKEARRAY(1,n,LAMBDA(r,c,1))),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array)),0)))

Desirable solution: Succinct formula solution(s) for horizontal/vertical stacking which take the array and n as inputs - possibly the direction too (i.e., horizontal or vertical).


Vertical stack 2 times:
={"A","B","C"}&EXPAND("",2,1,"")
Horizontal stack 3 times:
=TOROW({"A","B","C"}&EXPAND("",3,1,""))

I tried EXPAND(), but didn't know blanks can be used like that. Thank you, I can make this work for my actual use case.

Haha, it is from a youtube video I came across: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os8Yo3RiAVw

Excellent use of EXPAND() function.

Another way - define a lambda hrept:
=IF(n = 1, a, HSTACK(a, hrept(a, n - 1)))

called as
=hrept(array,number of repeats)

e.g.
=hrept({1,2,3},2)

or
=hrept({1,2,3;4,5,6},3)


vrept is similar:
=IF(n = 1, a, VSTACK(a, vrept(a, n - 1)))


The recursive solution is limited to a couple of thousand reps. Beyond this you would need the more obvious use of Reduce for a general formula that works with 2d arrays:
=LET(arr,{1,2,3;4,5,6},n,10,REDUCE(arr,SEQUENCE(n),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,a,HSTACK(arr,a)))))


For a relatively succinct all-in-one LAMBDA function, open Name Manager and define a new name called REPTA with the following formula:
=LAMBDA(array,n,[horizontal],
    IF(
        horizontal,
        CHOOSECOLS(array, TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE(n), SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(array))))),
        CHOOSEROWS(array, TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(n), SEQUENCE(, ROWS(array)))))
    )
)

The array can be a single value, row or column, as well as a 2D array or table.
By default, the formula will repeat the array vertically, if the optional [horizontal] argument is omitted (or set to FALSE or 0). To repeat the array horizontally, use TRUE or 1.
For example, to repeat a range 3 times:

Vertical: =REPTA(A1:C5, 3)
Horizontal: =REPTA(A1:C5, 3, 1)


Efficiency is relative to the size of the array. Smaller arrays will perform faster than larger arrays. The 5x3 array in the example shown above can output to column XFD without any noticeable calculation lag, using =REPTA(A1:C5, 5460, 1).
